# Trying to stream from DVB-T using libvlcsharp, get error "cache_block stream error: cannot pre fill buffer"

Tags: c#, vlc, libvlc, libvlcsharp

Here is my code:

```
static private void TuneDVB()
{
    using var libvlc = new LibVLC();
    using MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(libvlc);
    using Media media = new Media(libvlc, "dvb-t://frequency=562000000:bandwidth=0", FromType.FromLocation, ":dvb-adapter=0", ":live-caching=300");
    mp.Play(media);
}
```

When running it I get:

> [0000017b60b37650] cache_block stream error: cannot pre fill buffer

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does it work with vlc itself? With which syntax?

Comment: @cube45 Yes, the same command launches vlc and streams correctly. '''vlc dvb-t://frequency=562000000:bandwidth=0 :dvb-adapter=0:live-caching=300'''

Comment: Isn't `:bandwidth` a media option, like `:dvb-adapter`?

Comment: @cube45 separating bandwidth into a parameter gives the same error

Comment: By the way, you can't just put Play inside a using block. Play() starts playing, but doesn't wait for it to finish. Please have a look at the sample codes

Comment: please share full code _and_ full logs